# How to chain .then functions and callback success function in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, chaining

I'm trying to chain nested .then functions and call the success functions, but call back is calling in the starting itself.

```
//public method fn
function fn(callback) {
//calling the 1st API request
fn1()
  .then(function(response) {
    //2nd API request function
    call1(response);
  }, function(error) {
    return $q.reject({
    responseStatus: error.status
  });

  })
  // Returning response
  .then(function(response) {
    callback({
    responseStatus: 200
    });
  }, function(error) {
    callback({
      responseStatus: 500
    });
  });
}

function call1(response) {
  //2nd API
  fn2()
    .then(function(response) {
     //3rd API request function
        call2(response);
      }, function(error) {
        return $q.reject({
        responseStatus: error.status
      });
    });
}


function call2(response) {
  //3rd API request 
  fn3()
    .then(function(response) {
        return lastfunction();
      //here i need to callback the success  response status
      }, function(error) {
        return $q.reject({
        responseStatus: error.status
      });
    });
}


function fn1(){
 //some code 
 }
function fn2(){
//some code 
}
function fn3(){
//some code 
}

//Controller

//i will show response status callback here

if(response.status ==200){
  show output;
 }
 else{
  //response 500
  show errors;
  }
```

Basically i need to callback  "200" response status to other controller  on all service calls are successful and even if one request is failed i need to sent "500". with my code 'response status '200' is calling with the first .then function itself. I want to call this service calls as que

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `{ responseStatus: x }` object exists solely for the purpose of flow control, which can be provided naturally by the *success path* and *error path* of a promise returned by `fn()`;

Also, with promises, there's no need to pass a callback to `fn()` - indeed it is considered bad practice to do so.

So first,

- purge `callback` all through
- return a promise from each low level function
- simplify success chaining
- purge unnecessary error handlers

```
function fn() {
    return fn1().then(call1);
}
function call1() {
    return fn2().then(call2);
}
function call2() {
    return fn3().then(lastfunction);
}
function fn1() {
    //some code that returns a promise
}
function fn2() {
    //some code that returns a promise
}
function fn3() {
    //some code that returns a promise
}
```

Then, call as follows :

```
fn().then(function(response) {
    // success callback (your "200" condition)
    // show output;
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error callback (your "500" condition)
    // show error;
});
```

The `response` var will be whatever `lastfunction()` delivered. You have an issue if you want `response` to  be some aggregation of what is delivered by `fn1()`, `fn2()`, `fn3()` that is not already delivered by `lastfunction()`. That issue is comprehensively addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain/).

The `error` var will be the first `Error` to occur in the course of executing `fn()`, with no loss of information; `error.message` and `error.status` (if it exists) can be read/displayed.

Comment: But if at all my response is failed in call2 function, error callback is not called right with this approach.

Comment: By returning promises from the low level functions, error states naturally propagate upwards. Therefore wherever an error occurs, `call2()` or elsewhere, it will end up in the error handler.

Comment: @rUI7999 What exactly don't you like about what happens if there's a failure in call2()?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Can this pattern be condensed so that only N functions are required instead of N _pairs_ of functions? Do we really need _both_ fn2() and call2(), for example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the promises you create in order to chain them properly. Keep in mind when you use `.then()` you aren't modifying a promise, you're constructing a new one in the chain.

Your code with promises returned (formatting mine):

```
function fn(callback) {
  return fn1()
    .then(function(response) {
      return call1(response);
    }, function(error) {
      return $q.reject({
      responseStatus: error.status
    });

    })
    // Return response
    .then(function(response) {
      callback({
        responseStatus: 200
      });
    }, function(error) {
      callback({
        responseStatus: 500
      });
    });
}

function call1(response) {
  return fn2()
    .then(function(response) {
        return call2(response);
      }, function(error) {
        return $q.reject({
        responseStatus: error.status
      });
    });
}


function call2(response) {
  return fn3()
    .then(function(response) {
        return lastfunction();
      //here i need to callback the success  response status
      }, function(error) {
        return $q.reject({
        responseStatus: error.status
      });
    });
}


function fn1(){
 //some code 
 }
function fn2(){
//some code 
}
function fn3(){
//some code 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, i'm chaining them properly in order but i need to show the response status of the callback on success and errors

Comment: @rip1699 are you saying this code doesn't fix the issue? What is the behavior you seeing when you use it?

Comment: same behavior, i just forgot to mention return statements in the code. Basically response is calling after 1st function itself