# Return inside another function which itself is getting returned

Tags: javascript, promise

```
function getFirstUser() {
    return getUsers().then(function(users) {
               return users[0].name;
           });
}
```

Hi all, I'm learning js on my own and while reading an article on promises I came across this function. I coudn't understand why first return is required when the second return is doing the job. Thnaks in advance

Comment: this is not a well formed question. please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For your specific question you need to understand callback functions. take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177725/how-to-chain-then-functions-and-callback-success-function-in-angular-js)

Comment: @ramrunner - The question could use a little more explanation, but I understood it just fine and wrote a detailed answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 i know, i didn't downvote it. just suggested that OP edits it to bring it a bit more up to site standards.

Comment: @ramrunner will keep in mind from next time and thanks a ton guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the first return is returning the result of `getUsers().then()` from your `getFirstUser()` function.  So, the return value from `getFirstUser()` is a promise.

The second return is returning a value from the `.then()` promise callback.  In the world of promises, returning a value from a `.then()` handler sets the resolved value of that promise to that value.

The second return is NOT returning from the `getFirstUser()` function.  It's returning only from the `.then()` callback function and that return value goes back into the promise infrastructure that called the `.then()` handler.

Timing-wise, it's also useful to understand what happens in a timeline.  Here's a step-by-step description:

1. Someone calls `getFirstUser().then(somefn)`.
2. As `getFirstUser()` executes, it calls `getUsers()`.  That function initiates some asynchronous operation (perhaps a database query operation) and then returns a promise (I will call `p1`).  The database operation has not yet completed.
3. Then, on that returned promise `.then(fn)` is executed.  This just registers the function as a `.then()` callback and it returns a new promise.  The `.then()` handler is not yet called, it is stored to be called later.
4. `.then()` returns a new promise (I will call `p2`).
5. Then the function `getFirstUser()` is done and it returns the `p2` promise from the previous step.
6. Then, sometime later, the `getUsers()` promise resolves and causes the `.then()` handler that was previously registered on it to get called.
7. When that `.then()` handler gets called, your `return users[0].name;` executes and returns that value into the promise infrastructure.  That value becomes the resolved value of promise `p2` which is the promise that was returned from `getFirstUser()`.
8. Promise `p2` is now resolved.  This causes the original caller's `.then()` handler to be called (the one in step #1) and `someFn` is called and passed the first user resolved value.

Answer (score 1):

First `return` statement will return instance of the Promise itself.

The second `return` will fire in `callback` function, which was passed to the Promise.

Good articles about Promises: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Google developers portal](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).